# How to Add Total Hours Next to a Name

Tags: r

In a dataset, I am trying to add together total hours worked in a year, while my report has them listed line by line.

In essence, it's similar to what a sumproduct would be used for in Excel (only adding the hours if the name matched a previous column)

What would be the code in R used to do a similar thing?

E.G.

```
John Smith   8
John Smith   8
Hailey       9
Hailey      10
```

I would like to create another column which computes John's total as 16, and Hailey's as 19.

Comment: In the future, try to add a sample of your data with `dput(mydata)` for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution using `aggregate`

```
Hours = read.table(text="Name hours
'John Smith' 8
'John Smith' 8
Hailey 9
Hailey 10", 
header=TRUE)

aggregate(Hours$hours, list(Hours$Name), sum)
     Group.1  x
1     Hailey 19
2 John Smith 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
mydata[, totalHours := sum(hourCol), Name]
```

This should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the possible solutions using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(names = c("Emily", "John", "Emily", "Mike", "John"), hours = c(6, 7, 8, 5, 6))

df %>%
group_by(names) %>%
summarise(totals = sum(hours)) -> d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `doBy` package like so:

```
require(doBy)
summaryBy(hours_field ~ name_field, data = mydata, FUN = sum)
```

Comment: is it different from `aggregate` ?

Comment: It should produce the same results as something like `aggregate(mydata$hours_field, list(mydata$name_field), sum)`

Comment: `aggregate` also works with syntax `aggregate(hours_field ~ name_field, data = mydata, FUN = sum)`

Comment: seems that `doBy` offers interesting additional parameters, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/doBy/versions/4.6-1/topics/by-summary , but in this simple casei believe it is strictly equivalent